# Input type Color on Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome, html-input

I would like to know how to use `input[type=color]` on Chrome Packaged App. When I open the HTML file on the browser, the `input[type=color]` works well, it pop ups the color picker, but when I used it on an app, it doesn't do anything. Please help me how to enable this HTML5 feature.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking at the app from a mobile device? The web browser for the device might not support `input[type=color]`. It looks like iOS doesn't at this time. See the [compatibility tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color).